# Can Metals Have an Energy Gap?

Tags: solid-state-physics

It's a very silly question, but sill: Can metals have an energy gap in their bandstructures?

I would say yes, because the band gap is just $E_g = E_{c} - E_{v}$, I thought, where $E_c$ is the minimal energy in the conduction band and $E_{v}$ the maximal energy in the valence band.

But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap) doesn't have anything about metals, so I am left wondering. Thank you!!

Comment: In matals the Fermi Surface should not lie in a gap. Therefore within your definition of THE BAND GAP as $E_g=E_c-E_v$ metals do not have THE BAND GAP, because $E_c=E_v=E_F$ (This can be seen as a definition of a metal). As correctly stated by Emmy, Metals can have (and shurely have) gaps in their bandstructure.

Answer (score 3):

They can. The only requirement for a metal is to have its Fermi level (that is, the energy of the last occupied state at zero temperature) far enough from any gap. This is the case for Sodium for instance:

[image]

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. Actually, since it's in your image: Why does $2p$ contain $6N$ states? I am just curious, that's why I am asking, it has strictly speaking not to do with my original question.

Comment: In an atom there are 6, $2p$ states which constitute of the $|n=1,l=1,mz={-1,0,1},sz={1/2,-1,2}>$ states. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital

Comment: Okay. Going a bit further: $3d$ could then contain $10N$ states, $4f$ totally $14N$ states and so on, correct?

Comment: That is correct :)